# If $cl(g)=\{g\}$ can we imply that $g\in Z(G)?$

Tags: group-theory

I know that if  $z\in Z(G)$, the centre of group $G$ then it is true that $cl(z)=\{z\}$ where $cl(g)$ is the conjugacy class that contains element $g\in G$.

But what if $cl(g)=\{g\}$ can we imply that $g\in Z(G)?$

My attempt:
$$cl(g)=\{h\in G|\exists k\in G\text{ such that }h=k^{-1}gk\}=\{g\}$$
so there exists a $k$ in $G$ such that $g=k^{-1}gk$, but might not be the case for all $k$ in $G$ hence the above statement is false.

Thanks.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this as off-topic? It has a very clear attempt!

Comment: @Shaun thanks bro :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Rivaldo. Does my answer make sense to you? :)

Comment: @Shaun I just don't see why the h is arbitrary

Comment: I didn't use a $k$. However, for all $k'\in G$, by definition, we have $k'^{-1}gk'\in cl(g)$ as we have conjugated $g$ by $k'$.

Comment: yeh sorry h in your answer

Comment: Let $k'=h$ then. Does that help?

Comment: @Shaun think I see it now thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @Rivaldo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\operatorname{cl}(g)=\{g\}$, so if $h\in G$, then $h^{-1}gh\in \operatorname{cl}(g)$ implies $h^{-1}gh=g$, *i.e.*, $$gh=hg.$$ But $h$ was arbitrary in $G$. Hence $g\in Z(G)$.